# Use the subprocess Python module with Kivy on Raspbian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I tried call executable using python kivy on linux Raspbian.
My code not working correct, press button my app freezes and not open executable.
I tried on python interpreter:

```
>> from subprocess import call
>> call("7w.sh")
```

working fine, in python kivy executable not open...

Why executable not open?
My code:

Main.py

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')
from subprocess import call



class SmAgro(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SmAgro, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen_list = []

    def call_External_Pog(self):
        call(['7w.sh'])

    def changeScreen(self, next_screen):

        if next_screen == "configuracoes":
            self.ids.kivy_screen_manager.current = "configuracoes_screen"

        if next_screen == "equipamentos":
            self.ids.kivy_screen_manager.current = "equipamento_screen"

        if next_screen == "sobre":
            self.ids.kivy_screen_manager.current = "about_screen"

        if next_screen == "voltar":
            self.ids.kivy_screen_manager.current = "start_screen"


class SMAgroApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SMAgroApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self):
        return SmAgro()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SMAgroApp().run()
```

My smagro.kv

```
<SMAgro>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: kivy_screen_manager
        StartScreen:
            name: "start_screen"

        EquipamentoScreen:
            id: equipamento_screen
            name: "equipamento_screen"

        ConfiguracoesScreen:
            id: configuracoes_screen
            name: "configuracoes_screen"

        AboutScreen:
            id: about_screen
            name: "about_screen"

<StartScreen@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1,1,1,1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.45, 0.48
        Label:
            id: lbl_start_home
            text: 'SMAgro '
            color: [0,0,0,.200]
            font_size: root.height / 6
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            size_hint_x:0.3
            size_hint_y:1.6
            pos_hint: {'y': .5, 'x': .35}
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.changeScreen(self.text.lower())
            background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.375}
            size_hint: 1, 0.625
            text: "Equipamentos"
            text_size: self.size
            padding: 8, 8
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            Image:
                source: '../data/img/Truck-96.png'
                color: [1,1,1,1]
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 120
                x: self.parent.x + self.parent.height + 70

        Button:
            on_release: app.root.changeScreen(self.text.lower())
            background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: .5, 0.375
            text: 'Configuracoes'
            text_size: self.size
            padding: 8, 8
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            Image:
                source: '../data/img/Settings-64.png'
                color: [1,1,1,1]
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 90
                x: self.parent.x + self.parent.height - 15
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.call_External_Pog()
            background_color: [.4,1,.1,1]
            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: .5, 0.375
            text: 'Routerizador'
            text_size: self.size
            padding: 8, 8
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            Image:
                source: '../data/img/GPS Device-64.png'
                color: [1,1,1,1]
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 90
                x: self.parent.x + self.parent.height - 15

<EquipamentoScreen@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1,1,1,1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: lbl_equip
            text: 'Equipamento: '
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: root.height / 20
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            size_hint_x:0.3
            size_hint_y:1.8
        BoxLayout:
            pos: (220,410)
            size_hint_x: 0.621
            size_hint_y: 0.11
            TextInput:
                id: txt_equip
                font_size: '36sp'
                padding_y: (self.height - self.line_height) / 2
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'
        Label:
            id: lbl_operador
            text: 'Operador: '
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: root.height / 20
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            size_hint_x:0.3
            size_hint_y:1.6
        BoxLayout:
            pos: (220,356)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.11
            TextInput:
                id: txt_operador
                font_size: '36sp'
                padding_y: (self.height - self.line_height) / 2
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'
            Button:
                id: btn_search
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                Image:
                    source: '../data/img/Search-64.png'
                    y: self.parent.y - 28
                    x: self.parent.x- 10
        BoxLayout:
            pos: (400,356)
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0.11
            TextInput:
                id: txt_search
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'

        Label:
            id: lbl_medicao
            text: 'Medicao inicial: '
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: root.height / 20
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            size_hint_x:0.3
            size_hint_y:1.35

        BoxLayout:
            pos: (220,300)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.11
            TextInput:
                id: txt_medicao
                font_size: '36sp'
                padding_y: (self.height - self.line_height) / 2
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                id: lbl_turma
                text: 'Turma: '
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                font_size: root.height / 20
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'

            Label:
                text: 'Diurno:'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            CheckBox:
                group: 'turma'
                on_release: True

            Label:
                text: 'Noturno:'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            CheckBox:
                group: 'turma'

            Label:
                text: 'Vespertino:'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            CheckBox:
                group: 'turma'

        BoxLayout:
            pos: (10,10)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.12
            Button:
                on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
                id: btn_previous
                background_normal: '../data/img/Circled Left 2-64.png'
            Label:
                id: lbl_previous
                text: 'Voltar'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                font_size: root.height / 20
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'

        BoxLayout:
            pos: (630,10)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.12
            Label:
                id: lbl_next
                text: 'Avancar'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                font_size: root.height / 20
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            Button:
                id: btn_next
                background_normal: '../data/img/Circled Right 2-64.png'

<ConfiguracoesScreen@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1,1,1,1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: lbl_cod_equipamento
            text: 'Cod. equipamento: '
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: root.height / 20
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            size_hint_x:0.3
            size_hint_y:1.75
        BoxLayout:
            pos: (220,410)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.11
            TextInput:
                id: txt_cod_equipamento
                font_size: '36sp'
                padding_y: (self.height - self.line_height) / 2
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'
            Button:
                id: btn_search
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                Image:
                    source: '../data/img/Search-64.png'
                    y: self.parent.y - 28
                    x: self.parent.x- 10
        BoxLayout:
            pos: (400,410)
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0.11
            TextInput:
                id: txt_search
                border: 30, 30, 30, 30
                background_normal: '../data/img/AO734.png'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint_x: .5
            size_hint_y: .5
            Button:
                id: btn_update
                text: 'Atualizar dados'
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
                Image:
                    source: '../data/img/Available Updates-64.png'
                    y: self.parent.y - 22
                    x: self.parent.x- 10
            Button:
                id: btn_clear
                text: 'Limpar dados'
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
                Image:
                    source: '../data/img/Broom-64.png'
                    y: self.parent.y - 22
                    x: self.parent.x- 10
            Button:
                id: btn_senddata
                text: 'Enviar dados'
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
                Image:
                    source: '../data/img/Sent-64.png'
                    y: self.parent.y - 22
                    x: self.parent.x- 10
            Button:
                id: btn_save
                text: 'Gravar'
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
                Image:
                    source: '../data/img/Save-64.png'
                    y: self.parent.y - 22
                    x: self.parent.x- 10
        BoxLayout:
            pos: (10,10)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.12
            Button:
                on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
                id: btn_previous
                background_normal: '../data/img/Circled Left 2-64.png'
            Label:
                id: lbl_previous
                text: 'Voltar'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                font_size: root.height / 20
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'

        BoxLayout:
            pos: (630,10)
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            size_hint_y: 0.12
            Label:
                id: lbl_next
                text: 'Avancar'
                color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                font_size: root.height / 20
                font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
            Button:
                id: btn_next
                background_normal: '../data/img/Circled Right 2-64.png'

<AboutScreen@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1,1,1,1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        padding: root.width * .02, root.height * .02
        Label:
#            text: app.getText()
            color: [.4,1,.1,1]
            halign: "center"
            markup: True
            font_size: root.height / 20
            text_size: self.width, None
            center_y: .5
            on_ref_press: app.on_ref_press(*args)
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'

    BoxLayout:
        pos: (10,10)
        size_hint_x: 0.1
        size_hint_y: 0.11
        Button:
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
            id: btn_previous
            background_normal: '../data/img/Circled Left 2-64.png'
        Label:
            id: lbl_previous
            text: 'Voltar'
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: root.height / 20
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'

    BoxLayout:
        pos: (630,10)
        size_hint_x: 0.1
        size_hint_y: 0.11
        Label:
            id: lbl_next
            text: 'Avancar'
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: root.height / 20
            font_name: '../data/fonts/Segoe_UI.ttf'
        Button:
            id: btn_next
            background_normal: '../data/img/Circled Right 2-64.png'
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>p = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "7w.sh", ""])
>>>p.communicate()
```

I tested with Python3 on Raspberry Pi 3 under Minibian